# HTML/CSS: 100% container with background image - clickable link should be positioned on image?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I just hope there is any creative solution out there to solve the following problem:

I have a `#containter` with a background image applied

```
#container {
   height:400px;
   width:100%;
   background-image: url(http://cl.ly/NEvg/kv.jpg);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size: 1000px;
   background-position:center 0px;
}
```

The image I have has an area in it on which I want to position a clickable link.

[image]

In this example image I want to position an invisible `a#square` on top of the green square so that when I click ONLY the square the link is fired.

However the problem is that the background image is moving when scaling the browser window (I want it to move, so this is not the problem itself), but the link isn't.

See this live example: **http://jsfiddle.net/KDag7/**

Is there any creative CSS Way to make the link move along with the square in the image?

Thank you for your tipps and tricks.

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example of the image in your question (firewall blocked the image in the jsFiddle), if I understand what you're looking for, you can use this css:

```
 position:absolute;
 top:158px;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:64.5px;
```

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KDag7/21/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDag7/19/). I added `position:relative;` to the main image and `position:absolute;` to the link so that it is aligned to its parent. The positioning for the link can be achieved by:

```
position:absolute;
top:153px;
left:50%;
margin-left:63px;
```

Comment: very clever guys.. i like how you guys got the answer so fast! :)